# How to do this json data structure in the json diagram of Backand?

Tags: json, backand

first of all sorry if my english is not perfect…

I am new at backand. I am doing an app in ionic 2 using this json structure:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "name": "azzz",
      "genre": "male",
      "favorite": false
    },
    {
      "name": "abbb",
      "genre": "male",
      "favorite": false
    },
    {
      "name": "aeeee",
      "genre": "male",
      "favorite": false
    },
    {
      "name": "abaaaa",
      "genre": "male",
      "favorite": false
    }
  ],
  "b": [
    {
      "name": "bzzz",
      "genre": "male",
      "favorite": false
    },
    {
      "name": "babaa",
      "genre": "male",
      "favorite": false
    },
    {
      "name": "beeaaa",
      "genre": "male",
      "favorite": false
    },
    {
      "name": "baau",
      "genre": "male",
      "favorite": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Which i don’t know if dividing with letters is an optimal way to structure (ofcourse you can suggest me another way). But how can i use this structure in the json diagram of backand? For now i just want to GET the entirely json, and i want to add the letters and the names/genre/favorite inside the letters manually with the modal diagram. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

a and b are collections of objects with 3 properties so i guess it would look like that

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"dog",
      "fields":{  
         "name":{  
            "type":"string"
         },
         "genre":{  
            "type":"string"
         },
         "favorite":{  
            "type":"boolean"
         },
         "letters":{  
            "object":"letter"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "name":"letter",
      "fields":{  
         "dogs":{  
            "collection":"dog",
            "via":"letters"
         }
      }
   }
]
```